# Is chicken with yellowish parts spoiled?

Tags: chicken, fresh, color

Moved to new place (Europe), no nice butchers around, only store found has chickens with yellowed parts like in the attachment. I never seen tint like that on a chicken and wondering what does it mean? [image]

Comment: Maybe it's a corn fed chicken?  Some have [yellowish skin](https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/fresh-raw-chicken-leg-quarters-two-fresh-raw-chicken-leg-quarters-natural-cooking-ingredient-isolated-over-white-background-198893099.jpg) around the legs.

Comment: Very closely related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/108939/is-the-yellow-skin-of-a-raw-chicken-indicating-that-it-has-been-dyed. I am not closing yet, since there is some difference in the pictures (whole skin yellow vs. yellow patches only) and I don't know if this is significant - if somebody knows this for certain, please say it.

Comment: @rumtscho i did see this, but still posted question for the very same reason - not sure if yellow tint around legs is same as being yellow all over.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yellowing (particularly around the hocks) can be an indicator of the breed, and is more prevalent on younger chickens. For females it can fade as they reach laying age, although diet (high in corn) can also keep the yellowing.

Answer (score 1):

In South Africa, it is called *geelhoender* or yellow chicken. It means the chicken ate its natural diet of seeds, lentils, and various other good chicken food.

You also get *geelvet beesvleis* which is a type of beef that has been grass-fed. Its fat also has a yellow tint to it.

Beef that is fed corn gets the traditional white fat. The yellow fat is delicious. It is one of the few things that keeps me from going full vegan.

It should be considered a sign of quality.

Generally speaking yellow is not a bad color for meat. Certain herbivores just get that tint if fed a certain diet.

Green on the other hand is a sign of spoilage or that croc known as dry ageing.